# For how long can I postpone filing an application for adjustment of status (I-130)?

Tags: usa, greencard

My sister (US citizen) has filed an I-130 petition for me in January, 2006. The most recent Visa Bulletin states that the "final action date" for my category (F4, Brothers and Sisters of Adult U.S. Citizens) is "01JAN06" so I guess I can file an application for adjustment of status now.

But at this point I'm not sure whether I can/want to proceed with this.

How much time have I got to decide and file/not file? Does this thing have an expiry date? Thank you!

Comment: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/how-before-priority-date-current-will-i-letter-telling-me.html

Comment: "Adjustment of Status" is the process to get US permanent residency for someone in the US. If you are not in the US, you would go through "Consular Processing" abroad, with NVC and the US consulate in your country to get an immigrant visa. Which one did she indicate that you would do, on her I-130?